# how to cache cms block in magento for sessioned and non-sessioned visits?

Tags: php, caching, magento

For a Magento enterprise site, I have a CMS page (home page) which includes a certain block of code, 'my-products.phtml', using the following method within the CMS page content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/my-products.phtml"}}
```

The problem is that this block is really really slow and needs to be cached. The containing CMS page is cached for non-sessioned visitors, but once a user logs in, the page and the included block don't seem to be cached at all.

There's no session-specific code within the block so I'm wondering how to ensure that it is cached even when a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a descendant of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and use it's alias for the block type, like "yourmodule/product_list" instead of "catalog/product_list".

Follow [these instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput) to enable it's cache, the first example given is exactly what you need to display some product related data, but use a larger lifetime for more efficiency.

Comment: I tried this method and I'm seeing some performance gain for this block for registered users so it seems to be a good solution. Thank you so much, clockworkgeek.